# How to pass Object Context to a callback interface in Java

Tags: java, interface

Trying to get a handle on "callback interface".  The concept as I understand it make sense except for the following

```
//FromSomeClass1

MyInterface conect;

public void setInterface(MyInterface myInter)
{
     this.conect=myInter;
}

interface MyInterface 
{
     public void update(String str);
}
```

(Fuzziness starts here)
So when another class attempts to

```
//FromSomeClass2 implements MyInterface
...onCreate()
{
SomeClass1 newC = new SomeClass1()
newC.setInterface(this) ;

}
 update(String str){
 ....code  
 }
```

this will not work because I am passing to a new object ?  Unless I make the "conect" variable in Class1 static (Good Idea bad Idea...consequences ???)

Simply what is the correct way to pass the object back to "setInterface" method .

Hope that made sense and Thank You.

p.s.
To all those who want a good understanding of call backs this [link will help.](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/how-to-implement-callback-method/)

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You would normally do `MyInterface newC = new SomeClass1();` (new is not optional) and then `newC.update("Hello");`, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ Elliot Frisch I am simply attempting to grasp the correct concept in a step1...step2..step3..sort of way.  Reading documentation had me going in circles.  The objective is to callback to an update method in a different class when needed only.   Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider an example `Animal` interface with a single `says(String)` callback,

```
interface Animal {
    public void says(String msg);
}
```

Next, let's add a class that uses the `Animal` interface to say something -

```
class Say {
    public void say(Animal animal) {
        animal.says("Bawk");
    }
}
```

Now let's implement two different `Animal`(s) - we're going to have a `Cow` class and a `Sheep` class,

```
class Cow implements Animal {
    public void says(String msg) {
        System.out.printf("%s, I mean moo!%n", msg);
    }
}

class Sheep implements Animal {
    public void says(String msg) {
        System.out.printf("%s, I mean baah!%n", msg);
    }
}
```

Finally, to demonstrate the callback method we defined above -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Say say = new Say();
    say.say(new Cow());
    say.say(new Sheep());
}
```

Output is

```
Bawk, I mean moo!
Bawk, I mean baah!
```

Comment: Your walk through helps a great deal.  Can you clarify: I have seen and read about 2 callback techniques 1 is your way and another is the public void setInterface(MyInterface myInter)
{
     this.conect=myInter;
}..( this would go with the interface class)..way.  Am I crazy are there 2 call back techniques if so what are the differences.  Thanks.

Comment: @AhabLives In my code above, consider `says(String msg)`. What if it changed to `says(Say say)`? Then `say(Animal animal)` might have `animal.says(this);`. It's the same thing.

Comment: Frisch Wow...this may be asking too much but can you pepper the code above with the "//equivalent as.. animal.says(this);" way...I am telling you...you would save a lot of beginners a massive head ache.  Big big thanks again for all the help.

Comment: To all the people new to callbacks: This link will help a great deal http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/how-to-implement-callback-method/  My misconception was that I thought it was - a one way call from oject1 to obect2 only (once you register the object )....what's really happening is that BOTH objects are calling back to each other not JUST one.  A whole day lost because of one misconception.  So I guess the real question is...Is it OK to make the interface register variable static so that it IS a one way call ?

Comment: @AhabLives There are no interface police, if it works you *can* do it. However, it is far better to avoid globals when you can.

Answer (score 1):

Is not that you need to make it static. I mean, you could make everything in SomeClass1 and make the client register by calling an static method SomeClass1.setInterface(this)
I won't recommend doing that tough. This is an example fallowing your code:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class CallbackExample {

  interface MyInterface {
    public void update(String str);
  }

  static class SomeClass1 {
    private Set<MyInterface> connects = new HashSet<MyInterface>();

    public void register(MyInterface myInter) {
      this.connects.add(myInter);
    }

    public void doWork(String someParam) {
      for (MyInterface myInterface : connects) {
        myInterface.update(someParam);
      }
    }
  }

  static class SomeClass2 implements MyInterface {
    public void onCreate(SomeClass1 caller) {
      caller.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(String str) {
      System.out.println("Doing some logic in update for " + str);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Caller and callback creation are decoupled 
    SomeClass1 caller = new SomeClass1();
    SomeClass2 callback = new SomeClass2();

    // alternative 1. Preferred
    caller.register(callback);

    // alternative 2. Fallowing your example
    callback.onCreate(caller);

    caller.doWork("param1");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good example of the use of callbacks is the `android-async-http` library.  To make a HTTP request, you call a method and pass in the details of the request along with an object that implements a certain callback interface.  The request method returns immediately, but after the request is complete, the library's worker thread sets up a call in the main thread to a method on the callback object you provided.